# Requesting domain name in nuxt.config.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am setting up a multi language site with Nuxt JS and I have a situation where it is troublesome to set up .ENV files for each domain.

I am wondering if there is a way to pick up the domain name in the nuxt.config.js file?

Comment: Could you elaborate  on what is troublesome?

Comment: I actually do not know the reason why setting up .ENV for each domain is not easy in this case since there is someone else working on the server-setup and hosting. I was just looking for possible alternatives to having specific .ENV files.