# Dynamic prismic endpoint for nuxt module

Tags: nuxt.js, prismic.io

In nuxt.config.js, the prismic module can be added as such

```
modules: [["@nuxtjs/prismic", {
"endpoint": "https://repository-id.cdn.prismic.io/api/v2",
"apiOptions": {
  "routes": [{
    "type": "page",
    "path": "/:uid"
  }]
}}]]
```

Can the subdomain value be used to populate the prismic endpoint dynamically? We would like to use the same codebase for multiple sites, but each site has its own repository.

example1.domain.com

```
modules: [["@nuxtjs/prismic", {
"endpoint": "https://example1-content.cdn.prismic.io/api/v2",
"apiOptions": {
  "routes": [{
    "type": "page",
    "path": "/:uid"
  }]
}}]]
```

example2.domain.com

```
modules: [["@nuxtjs/prismic", {
"endpoint": "https://example2-content.cdn.prismic.io/api/v2",
"apiOptions": {
  "routes": [{
    "type": "page",
    "path": "/:uid"
  }]
}}]]
```

Comment: Would it be possible for you to have a custom .env file for each subdomain?

Comment: That should be possible, but it would still need to check the subdomain and load the correct .env file based on the subdomain. So the main issue here is to populate the endpoint dynamically based on the subdomain

Comment: Exactly. So, if your server/hosting is set up in a way so that each domain gets sent a unique .env file, then you can just add the correct endpoint to each .env file.

However, I had a project a while ago where having a unique .env for each domain was not possible, so I asked here about the possibility of fetching the domain from nuxt.config.js. I never got an answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57065510/requesting-domain-name-in-nuxt-config-js